# Should I start Amiga's copper list using COPJMP1 or is it superfluous?

Tags: amiga

According to the documentation I have ("Hardware" by J.Schimanski) after setting the copper list COP1LCx under `$dff080` it should be started by writing an arbitrary value into COPJMP1 under `$dff088`. However my copper list works "automatically" without the latter step. What is the right way of doing it? Do I need this starting step?

I use Amiga 500 with ECS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Copper list is started automatically with every vertical sync. If you need it to start at some other time you need to write to COPJMP1.

Comment: Can you give me an example of "at some other time"?

Comment: Well, for example you could build separate Copper lists/viewports for several screens you'd want to display simultaneously (below each other). Without merging the separate viewport lists to a single, larger one, you could write each start address to COP1LC and then write to COPJMP1 to switch to that viewport.

It's a bit like an unconditional  `JMP` for the Copper, while writing to COP1LC alone just primes the vector for the next run.